# Question for my entity relationships

Tags: database-design, schema, database-diagrams

I'm not sure how I should think regarding my database design. I have made this database schema below. And I'm trying to think about the relationship between the entities. I have read through online that **many-to-many** should be avoided as much as possible and it makes sense. But in my case here, can it be avoided and how? The idea is that there should exists only "unique" items in the WalletStorage and WalletPlatform table that one or many can be owned by a Wallet.

For example, my reasoning is that a **Wallet** can have many **WalletPlatform** and **WalletStorage** that it owns. Also, a **WalletPlatform** and a **WalletStorage** can not just be part of one **Wallet**. But soon as I implement this in for example Hibernate for a **one-to-many** relationship between **Wallet** and **WalletPlatform** and **WalletStorage** it attaches a column in the **WalletPlatform** and **WalletStorage** for each row with the `wallet_id`. It probably does exactly what it supposed to do, but I'm clearly missunderstanding something here.

In the wallet_storage table the structure is this:

```
id    name     wallet_id
```

In the wallet_platform table:

```
id    name     description    wallet_id
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE - you question isn't very clear - many to many relationships aren't something to be avoided, they describe how entities are related.  What exactly are the relationships between your entities, it isn't clear from your question or your diagram.  Consider posting table definitions.

Comment: In your diagram, the 1-M connections are the wrong way around if the FK's are correct (which they probably aren't: a wallet can contain only one currency?).